# Can't create a new Cognitive Service in Azure Portal

Tags: azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I need to migrate a LUIS service into another subscription, but when I create the new service no Pricing Tier option provided to me. So I can't create the resource.

I try to create the resource in the same subscription where the original is, but the same thing happens.

[image]

Comment: Do you confirm that the screenshot is from portal.azure.com? Is the screenshot original or modified? Did you try to use another resource group and/or Location? Allowed pricing tiers can vary based on those parameters.

Comment: Can you try changing the subscription or the resource group and give it a try? Also, the location option doesn't show up.

Comment: Solved, Azure's problem seemed to be. The resource creation template was not what it should be. After an hour I tried again and the template had changed